# Condition For Local Extremum And A More Questions

Tags: functions, optimization, maxima-minima

I am going to link a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnOXL.png) of the question (as well as a short solution/explanation which I did not understand).

> #### Question
>
> Let $f: [a, b] \to\mathbb R$ be a function such that for $c \in (a, b)$
>
> $$f^i(c) = f^{ii}(c) = f^{iii}(c) = f^{iv}(c) = f^v(c) =
>  0$$
>
> where $f^n(c)$ represents the nth derivative of $f(c)$
>
> Choose the correct options
>
> 1. $f$ has a local extremum at $x = c$
> 2. $f$ has neither a local extremum nor a local minimum at $x = c$
> 3. $f$ is necessarily a constant function
> 4. none of these —> (this is the correct option)
>
> #### Explanation
>
> ('Because' symbol here please. Couldn't find it on my keyboard) $$f^i(c) = f^{ii}(c) = f^{iii}(c) = f^{iv}(c) = f^v(c) = 0$$
>
> Now, if $n$ is the least positive integer such that $f^n(c) \ne 0$,
>   then it is not clear whether $n$ is even or odd. So, nothing can be
>   said whether $f(x)$ has local extremum at $x = c$ or $n = t$.

---

After you are done with the picture, here are **my questions**:

1. What exactly is the condition for $f(x)$ to have a local extremum? Till now, I used to solve for $f'(x) = 0$ and then check the sign of $f''(x)$ at that point. Do I need to check higher order derivates of $f(x)$ as well?
2. If $f'(a) = f''(a) = 0$, then does it mean that there is neither a maximum nor a minimum at $x = a$?
3. Can there be global/local maxima at boundary points of the domain? For eg: If the domain of $f(x)$ is $(0,50)$ and it attains maximum value at $x = 50,$ then does it count as a maximum?
4. What is the condition for $f(x)$ to be a constant function? I think that all higher order derivatives of $f(x)$ should be zero. Is this correct?

---

#### Edit

<sub>Currently, I am banned from asking more questions because I ask "bad" questions, i.e., questions which got downvoted (a couple of such questions including this one) primarily because they were poorly formatted. So, I have spent a little over half an hour trying to improve this question (the other one has since been formatted by a more experienced user but still has a negative score) and I would appreciate a few upvotes so that I can ask new questions. ——> Update : I can now ask new questions. Thanks everyone !!</sub>

Comment: Doubt no. 2 got cleared.. can anyone help with the other three? :)

Comment: Can I use my physics SE rep to start a bounty on this?

Comment: Perhaps you will find it useful to know that in standard English, "doubt" is not synonymous with "question", but means something more like "uncertainty", or when used as a verb, to doubt is to be uncertain. To say "I have some doubts about your posted answer." would often mean you're not sure the answer is correct, but to say "I have some questions about your posted answer." means you want some specified items of information about it.

Comment: were you looking for `\because`, which gets rendered as $\because$ ?

Comment: Currently, @AnuragBaundwal, you are no longer question-banned. But you will still be close to the threshold of the algorithm, so tread carefully when asking your next question.

Comment: Yes, Daniel. I'll be more careful. And thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "explanation" seems to assume that you know a theorem that says something about the least positive integer $n$ for which $f^{(n)}(c)$ is $0,$ and whose conclusion says something about whether there is a maximum or minimum or neither of the above. It might be better for you to include the theorem in your question.

Here is an application to the situation where $f'(c)=f''(c) = f'''(c)=0$ and $f''''(c)>0.$ If the function is reasonably well behaved, then $f''''>0$ in some neighborhood of $c,$ so  Then the third derivative is INCREASING in that neighborhood, so it must go from negative to positive. Since $f'''<0$ to the left of $c,$ $f''$ must be decreasing there, and likewise $f''$ is increasing to the right of $c.$ Thus $f''>0$ near $c,$ except exactly at $c.$ Therefore $f$ is concave upward near $c.$ Therefore there is a local minimum at $c.$

There is a theorem that says that if $f$ has first and second derivatives in some open interval containing $c$ and $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c)>0,$ then $f$ has a local minimum at $c,$ and if $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c)<0,$ then $f$ has a local maximum at $c.$ But that theorem says nothing about what happens when $f'(c)=0$ and $f''(c)=0.$ That is the situation treated by some theorems dealing with values at $c$ of higher derivatives of $f.$ There are some functions $f$ for which $f'(c) = 0 = f''(c)$ and there is a local minimum at $c.$ A very simple example is $f(x) = x^4$ and $c=0.$ There are others for which there is a maximum, and one example is $f(x) = -x^4$ and $c=0.$ And there are some for which there is no local extremum (i.e. maximum or minimum). $f(x) = x^5$ and $c=0$ is an example.

To say that you always have to look at the first and second derivatives is false. It can be done that way, but in some cases you can use only the first derivative and in some cases no derivative at all. You don't need any derivatives in order to know that $f(x) = x^2$ has a global minimum at $x=0,$ or that $f(x) = \sin x$ has a global maximum at $x = \pi/2.$ And sometimes only the first derivative is enough; for example, if $f$ is continuous and you show that $f'>0$ on the interval $(-\infty,c)$ and is negative on the interval $(c,+\infty),$ then you can conclude that $f$ has a global maximum at $c$ without knowing anything about the second derivative.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd like a little more detail. Even though it clarifies that knowing about the first and second derivatives is not always enough to know about maxima and minima, it still doesn't clearly explain the condition for local extremum. For example, let's say that the 1st, 2nd & 3rd derivatives of f(x) are zero at x = c but the 4rth derivative is positive. What can we say here? Can we extend the second derivative test to nth derivative test? Also, what about ques. no. 3? And I think that the ans. to ques. no. 4 is that all derivatives should be zero, right?

Comment: @AnuragBaundwal : The quoted question is stated in language that is like what would be used if it were a homework exercise, and its content makes it look as if you would have seen some theorem of the sort described in my opening sentence. The content of that theorem may answer your question. However, maybe I'll post something further about this.

Comment: Suppose the first three derivatives are $0$ at $c,$ and $f''''(c)>0.$ If the function is reasonably well behaved, then $f''''>0$ in some neighborhood of $c,$ so  Then the third derivative is INCREASING in that neighborhood, so it must go from negative to positive. Since $f'''<0$ to the left of $c,$ $f''$ must be decreasing there, and likewise $f''$ is increasing to the right of $c.$ Thus $f''>0$ near $c,$ except exactly at $c.$ Therefore $f$ is concave upward near $c.$ Therefore there is a local minimum at $c. \qquad$ @AnuragBaundwal

Comment: @AnuragBaundwal : I've added the content of the comment above to the answer, in the second paragraph. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. Indeed, after searching, I found that there is an "nth derivative test" in one of my reference books, and it uses reasoning similar to yours (in your second para) — Let's say that n is odd and that the first n derivatives are zero. Then, if the (n + 1)th derivative is < 0 then maxima, > 0 minima. If n is even, neither maxima nor minima. Lastly, and this isn't really related to the  question in the title — what about my question no. 3? It's a thing of convention, with a short yes/no answer, so I thought I should get it clarified, too.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#First_derivative_test), if $f''(a)=0$, the test is inconclusive.

Referring to your example, consider:

$1) f(x)=x^6$ for $x\in [-1,1]$. Then:
$$f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)=f^{(4)}(0)=f^{(5)}(0)=0, \\
f^{(6)}(0)=6!\ne 0; \\
f(0)=0 \text{ (min)}$$

$2) f(x)=x^7$ for $x\in [-1,1]$. Then:
$$f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)=f^{(4)}(0)=f^{(5)}(0)=f^{(6)}(0)=0, \\
f^{(7)}(0)=7!\ne 0; \\
f(0)=0 \text{ (not max, not min)}$$

Comment: That clears up my second doubt. Thanks! :)

Comment: See my edits for proper use of \text{} in MathJax. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Michael Hardy, thank you for editing the extremes.